# how to select all fields in a table columns into a variable microsoft access

Tags: ms-access, vba

how to select an entire column in microsoft access vba into one variable.
for example sudo code

```
dim colum1 as variant

column1=select column1 from table1
```

is this possible? or do i need to loop throught the values in the columns and then add into the variable?
Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/129856

Comment: @Tim: +2 if I could ! I did not know that fantastrick !!!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Tim Williams comment, what you would most commonly want in Access is a recordset:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDB.Openrecordset("SELECT Field1 FROM MyTable")
```

You can now manipulate this recordset.

You can limit the selection with a WHERE statement.

Adding column values to an array is an unusual requirement.